# Flow is not setting values to Null

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, null

In the flow I have a very simple get of records. I only return the first record. I have the box checked,

[image: no records found set to null]

However, when I test my var with '{!var.Id}', IS NULL = true, in a screen component. It is showing as a an empty string. This is causing significant problems, because an apex class later in the flow needs to have a null value if no record is found.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Two possibilities- 1. may be the value is empty string being passed on to the flow variable. 2. are you sure you are not resetting the variable anywhere else in the flow?

Comment: The initial var was a text type, which salesforce has in it's documentation that it will not set as null. However, when using a var record type, the {!rec.Id} is not getting set to null despite configuring the "Get Records" different ways. i.e. the three different options that salesforce provides in the Get Record. I think this is a bug on SF.

Comment: Going to update the post with more in depth screen shots for more context.